# Iterating Through Rows of Pandas DataFrame - change series value based on values in another series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When iterating through the rows of a DataFrame, how do I change the value of one element based on the value on another element in the same row?

I have the following code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row["A"] in mult):
        row["B"] = row["B"] * mult[row["A"]]
```

This iterates through each row and sees if the value in "A" is present in a key in the dictionary (`mult`). If it is in the dictionary, series "B" is multiplied by the floating point value coming from the dictionary.

The code runs without reporting an error - but when I examine the df it hasn't changed in the DataFrame.

Thanks - Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to reinitialise local variable `row`.
The correct code could be as follows:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row["A"] in mult:
        df["B"].iloc[index] = row["B"] * mult[row["A"]]
```

However, that is an ugly way to handle middle-size or large DataFrames.
The more pythonic solution could be as follows:

```
df["B"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["B"] * mult[x["A"]] if x["A"] in mult else x["B"], axis=1)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks @night_bat! Now I need to learn more about lambda function